# How do I determine if two similar band names represent the same band?

Tags: c#, string, spell-checking

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to match our database of Bands and venues with a number of external services.

Basically I'm looking for some direction on the best method for determining if two names are the same. For Example:

- Our database venue name - "The Pig and Whistle"
- service 1 - "Pig and Whistle"
- service 2 - "The Pig & Whistle"
- etc etc

I think the main differences are going to be things like missing "the" or using "&" instead of "and" but there could also be things like slightly different spelling and words in different orders.

What algorithms/techniques are commonly used in this situation, do I need to filter noise words or do some sort of spell check type match?

Have you seen any examples of something simlar in c#?

UPDATE: In case anyone is interested in a c# example there is a heap you can access by doing a [google code search for Levenshtein distance](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=lang%3Ac%23+Levenshtein+distance&hl=en&btnG=Search+Code)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The canonical (and probably the easiest) way to do this is to measure the **[Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)** between the two strings. If the distance is small relative to the size of the string, it's probably the same string. Note that if you have to compare a lot of very small strings it'll be harder to tell whether they're the same or not. It works better with longer strings.

A smarter approach might be to compare the Levenshtein distance between the two strings but to assign a distance of zero to the more obvious transformations, like "and"/"&", "Snoop Doggy Dogg"/"Snoop", etc.

Comment: Awesome, do you think that it would still be effective say if I removed words like "the", "and" and "&" ?

Comment: Assigning a distance of zero is equivalent to removing them from the string, yes. You could also strip whitespace/punctuation to prevent extra spaces from affecting it. But just be careful that those aren't significant to the band name. For example, "!!!" is the name of a band (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/!!!).

Comment: You might want to consider removing stop words from the text strings - (like "the" "an" "and" etc.) databases of English language stop words are pretty easy to come by.

Comment: I came across this blog post which implements this algorithm and a few others in c# with source code: http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/stevehawley/archive/2009/01/26/string-similarity-and-extension-methods.aspx

Comment: @anthonyvscode There is actually a bug with steve's LD code that gives different distances if you swap the order of the strings around. However, the link that steve gives credit to http://www.merriampark.com/ldcsharp.htm does not have the same bug.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this a while ago, I used the the Discogs database (which is public domain), which also tracks artist aliases;

You can either:

- Use an [API call](http://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:database,header:database-artist) (`namevariations` field).
- Download the [monthly data dumps](http://www.discogs.com/data/) (`*_artists.xml.gz`) & import it in your database. This contains the same data, but is obviously a lot faster.

One advantage of this over the [Levenshtein distance)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1918852/660921) solution is that you'll get a lot less false matches.
For example, `Ryan Adams` and `Bryan Adams` have a score of `2`, which is quite good (lower is better matches, `Pig and Whistle` and `Pig & Whistle` has a score of `3`), yet they're obviously different people.

While you could make a smarter algorithm (which also looks at string length, for example), using the alias DB is a lot simpler & less error-phone; after implementing this, I could completely remove the solution that was suggested in the other answer & had better matches.

Answer (score 0):

[soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) may also be useful

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @BryanCrosby: generally agreed, but repeating the fundamental soundex algorithm here is a waste of space. Even if the underlying link vanishes, the name of the algorithm should suffice. Unless google also vanishes ;)

Answer (score 0):

In bioinformatics we use this to compare DNA- or protein sequences all the time.

There are plenty of algorithms, you probably want to look at *global alignments*.

In this respect the [Needleman-Wunsch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) is probably what you seek.

If you have particularly long recurring strings to compare you might also want to consider heuristic searches like BLAST.