# matching characters in strings in visual C#

Tags: c#

I'm working on visual C#
to calculate the word error rate 
I have one textbox for the refrence which is the correct sentance 
and one for the hypothesis which is wrong one.

in order to calculate WER I need to calculate :
substitution : the word that has been changed which was my first question
Insert : the words that had been inserted in the sentence
Deleted: the words that had been deleted from the original sentence

For EX:

refrence: This is a NPL program.
hypothesis: it is an NPL cool.

it: substitution 
is: correct
 an :substitution 
NPL:correct 
 program: deleted
cool: inserted

I tried the algorithm that dasblinkenlight proposed ( thank you so much by the way )
I worked but there is a runtime error I couldn't figure it out, in line

```
int x=  Compute(buffer[j], buffer_ref[i]);
```

Index was outside the bounds of the array.

and here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string [] hyp = new string[20];
        string [] refrence = new string[20];
        string [] Anser= new string[20];
        string[] buffer = new string[20];
        string[] buffer_ref = new string[20];
        int count = 0; // number of words 
        string ref2=" " ;
        string hyp2 = " ";
        string Anser2 = " ";
        string buffer2 = " ";

        int corecct_c=0;
        int corecct_d = 0;
        int corecct_i = 0;

        //====================================================================

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 19; ++i)
            {
                hyp[i] = null;
                buffer[i] = null;
            }
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            refrence = this.textBox2.Text.Split(' ');
            buffer_ref = this.textBox2.Text.Split(' ');


        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hyp = this.textBox1.Text.Split(' ');
            buffer = this.textBox1.Text.Split(' ');
            //hyp = this.textBox1.Text;
            // fname1.Add(this.textBox1.Text);


        }

        public void correct(string[] R)
        {

            for (int i = 0; (i <= 19) && (R[i] != "."); ++i)
            {

                if (buffer[i] == refrence[i])
                { buffer[i] = "0";
                buffer_ref[i] = "0";
                    corecct_c = corecct_c + 1;
                    Anser[i] = "C";
                }
            }

        }

        // function that compute 2 strings
        public static int Compute(string s, string t)
        {
            int n = s.Length;
            int m = t.Length;
            int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];

            // Step 1
            if (n == 0)
            {
                return m;
            }

            if (m == 0)
            {
                return n;
            }

            // Step 2
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
            {
            }

            for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++)
            {
            }

            // Step 3
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                //Step 4
                for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
                {
                    // Step 5
                    int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

                    // Step 6
                    d[i, j] = Math.Min(
                        Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                        d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
                }
            }
            // Step 7
            return d[n, m];
        }


        public void sub(){

            for (int j = 0;j<=19;j++) 
         {
             if (buffer[j].IndexOf("0") != -1)
             {


                 for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
                 {

                     if (buffer_ref[j].IndexOf("0") != -1)
                     {

                       int x=  Compute(buffer[j], buffer_ref[i]);
                       if (x > 3)
                       {
                           buffer[j] = "0";
                           Anser[j] = "S";

                       }


                     }//end if

                 } 

             }//end if 


        }//end for 

        }// end fun

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            correct(refrence);
            sub();
            for (int i = 0; (i <= 19) && (refrence[i] != "."); ++i)
            {
                //loop intialize 
                ref2 = ref2 + " " + refrence[i];
                hyp2 = hyp2 + " " + hyp[i];
                Anser2 = Anser2 + " " + Anser[i];
                buffer2 = buffer2 + " " + buffer[i];
                count++;
                            }

            listBox1.Items.Add(" Refrence :" + ref2);
            listBox1.Items.Add(" HYp :" + hyp2);
            listBox1.Items.Add(" Anser:" + Anser2);
            listBox1.Items.Add(" buffer:" + buffer2);
            listBox1.Items.Add(count);

        } 




        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

can you help me please ?

Comment: Welcome, just a heads up, we already have a few similar questions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344514/testing-for-similar-string-content, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747169/c-sharp-comparing-similar-strings and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918838/match-similar-names-in-c-sharp

Comment: On what degree is "similar"? How many letters has to be the same for it to decide that the two strings are "similar"?

Comment: Thank you @NathanKoop just about to bring that up ;)

Comment: I've used the Levenshtein Distance algorithm
but I've had some trouble ^^" there is a runtime error I couldn't handle :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a built-in way to test if two lines are identical, but there is no built-in way to tell if two lines are similar. You need to implement an algorithm that measures string similarity, such as the [*Levenshtein Distance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) - a very common [*Edit Distance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) algorithm. Lines with small edit distance can be declared similar depending on some threshold specific to your requirements.

Comment: +1 you were faster :) A C# implementation of the Levenstein Distance algorithm: http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein

Comment: can you please check my code , I believe I done something wrong but I don't now what

Comment: this is a method to calculate the place of substitution

Comment: I've wrote all of the code can you please tell me what you think

Comment: @Glory I tried out your implementation of Levenshtein, it looks good ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/yUM9H9)). As far as the rest of your code goes, I cannot tell you much, because I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for trying, you have helped me alot thank you ^^ and I will try to find out what went wrong

Comment: actually I'm still looking for some help , but if I found an answer I will gladly do it ^^

Comment: @Glory Consider posting a separate question: as far as matching characters in strings goes, this question has an answer, and is, therefore, highly unlikely to get much additional attention from the community. Anyway, a well-formulated new question has much higher chances to be of use to you. Good night!

Comment: found what I was looking for .. thanx for UR help ^^

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use an [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) that compares the "distance" between two strings:

> The closeness of a match is measured in terms of the number of
>   primitive operations necessary to convert the string into an exact
>   match. This number is called the edit distance between the string and
>   the pattern. The usual primitive operations are:
>
> ```
> insertion: cot → coat
> deletion: coat → cot
> substitution: coat → cost
> ```

Comment: can you please check my code , I believe I done something wrong but I don't now what

Comment: What is buffer doing in your code? To figure the "distance" between `a1` and `a2` you need to do: `var distance = LevenshteinDistance.Compute(a1, a2)`

Comment: the buffer is a temp where i can delete the correct words so the code can skip them